# Problemas com atributo :not() do css

Tags: html, css3, css-seletores, scss

estou com um problema estou editando um `h2`com css e dentro desse `h2` tem um `span` porem queria aplicar o estilo no `h2`porem não quero que o estilo se aplique no meu `span` estou usando o seletor `:not(span)` para isso porem não funciona segue meu código:

html

```
<div class="text-center box-product band-product">
                        <h2>Quero<br>anunciar meu<br><span>produto</span></h2>
                        <a href="#" title="Saiba mais">Saiba mais <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
                    </div>
```

SCSS:

```
.box-product{
        background-color: $light-gray;
        h2:not(span){
            line-height: 30px;
            @include gradient-orange(#f97c16, #feb226);
            -webkit-background-clip: text;
            -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
            span{
                color: $gray;
                font-weight: normal;
                font-family: "good_vibes", sans-serif;
                font-size: 2em;
                text-transform: capitalize;
            }
        }
    }
```

percebam que a cor que estou aplicando no `h2` está se aplicando no meu span tbm não quero isso como posso resolver segue a imagem
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Cara eu acho que vc acabou complicando as coisas com o `not()` sem precisar.

Veja no exemplo abaixo como vc pode corrigir o problema apenas voltando com a cor do texto no `span` assim `-webkit-text-fill-color: gray;`

```css
.box-product{
    background-color: #000;
}
.box-product h2 {
    line-height: 30px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#f97c16, #feb226);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
.box-product h2 > span {
    color:gray;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: "good_vibes", sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: gray;
    background-image: linear-gradient(gray, gray);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center box-product band-product">
    <h2>Quero<br>anunciar meu<br><span>produto</span></h2>
    <a href="#" title="Saiba mais">Saiba mais <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
</div>
```

---

Vou deixar aqui um exemplo caso vc quera entender melhor o seletor `:not()`.

No exemplo abaixo eu tenho uma tag `<h1>` e dentro dela tenho mais duas tags uma `<span>` e uma `<label>`, ai eu usei o seletor not para colorir tudo dentro do `h1`, menos o `span`.

**Repare que o que está dentro do `h1` é filho do `h1`**, então usar `h1:not()` significa que **"todos os `h1` que não ( regra css)"**, Ex: se vc fizer isso `h1:not(.tit) {color: red}` todos os h1 ficam vermelhos, menos o que tiver a classe `.tit`

**Veja o exemplo:**

```css
body {color: green;}
h1 {color: blue;}
h1 > *:not(label) { color: red; }

/* todos P ficaram azul, menos o com a classe .tit*/
p:not(.tit) {
    color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<h1>text H1 
    <span class="classico">tag span</span>
    <label>tag label</label>
</h1>
<p>Mais um texto<p>
<p class="tit">Mais um texto<p>
<p>Mais um texto<p>
```

Comment: então o problema de fazer isso é que alem de repetir o código perceba que no span tem uma borada laranja do h2 bem sutiu mais da para ver  por isso acredito que o :not() iria me ajudar 100% entende seráq que estou usando errado o atributo com o scss tem alguma forma de faze-lo funcionar ?

Comment: @Kirito vou fazer um teste e te falo

Comment: beleza agradeço muito :)

Comment: @Kirito fiz uns testes aqui eu até consigo desconsiderar o color no span, mas quando vc usa o background não tem como não faze-lo passar por traz do filho também, a não ser que o filho tenho a seu próprio background. É tipo quando vc coloca opacity na div e tudo que está dentro dela também fica com opacidade... No momento além de repetir as classes, inclusive colocando um background-image: linear-gradient(gray, gray); no span para tirar o contorno laranja não consigo outra solução

Comment: entendi amigo muito obrigado se puder atualizar a resposta com o teste que vc fez removendo a borada laranja agradeço

Comment: @Kirito já edite, mas na verdade só repeti as classe no span mas mudando a cor para `gray` talvez não seja a solução perfeita, mas não consegui pensar em nada melhor, principalmente pelo fato do span estar dentro do H1 e estar "herdando" alguns estilos e bg.

Comment: @Kirito no final da minha resposta fiz outro Edit, e inclui um exemplo prático e mais umas infos sobre como usar o not(), acho que pode te dar uma luz na hora de fazer o aninhamento com SCSS